# It is okay to not cool motherboard below 40C?

Tags: motherboard, fan, cooling, temperature

I have ASUS TUF SABERTOOTH Z97 MARK 1/USB 3.1 motherboard. At idle, motherboard shows temperatures between 29-37C. I'm currently waiting for PWM fans to come and will connect them directly to MB.

Is it okay to shut down all the fans (except 1 on the top) if the MB temperature is below 40 C?

[Thermal Radar 2 scr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTCbM.jpg)

Comment: 40'c is perfectly fine for any component inside your computer.

Comment: Is the "Motherboard" sensor on the bottom right of your image? if so, then yes, it is safe, but be a little bit concerned when it reaches 40, as it is very likely that other components in the box are much hotter. for instance, if CPU usage causes Motherboard temperature to rise, then your heat evacuation rate is insufficient. You can usually have your CPU cores at above 90C before the Motherboard hits 50C.

Comment: Be careful: not all the components of a computer have a thermal sensor: some one could be too hot and you will have no readings. I know this could sound a bit stupid, but a trick I always use is: touch the heatsink (of anything), and if you can keep your finger, its temperature is OK.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, note that in this case, the "Motherboard" sensor appears to be a general temperature (often called "System" temp), not a sensor attached to a component that is actually generating heat the way the CPU, RAM, power cores, and controller chips do. As such its really a measure of how well your entire cooling system is doing in evacuating heat from the box, rather than an assessment of the health of any given component.

Comment: The temperatures you are providing far exceed the temperatures you would get with stock cooling, so yes, those temperatures are fine.  If you disable the fans then you won't keep those temperatures, what is the point of those temperatures, if you disable fans.

Comment: @FrankThomas All the sensors on this particular mb, are actually all temperature sensors. But I agree with you, that I it doesn't show all the temp measurements of all the components. Also I have 3 external sensors, which I didn't attach yet to anything.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Yes I'm aware of that, since it's how all motherboard temperature sensors work. My point still stands. I can't think of any component inside a PC that is *not* certified to work at 40'c air temperature.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, I am not understaning your point then. My point is that if the system box is 40C, then the components like CPU may be as much as 100C. The System/Motherboard temp does not assert anything about the temps of the individual components at all. the only thing it tells you is whether your overall cooling strategy is evacuating enough heat from the entirety of the system, so you can't say that when the system temp is 40 that all the components are healthy.

Comment: @FrankThomas: The point is that all components are designed to work in an *environment* that is 40'c ambient. It doesn't matter what temperature the components are. Component spec sheets always state what the acceptable range is for temperature *around* the component. Knowing what temperature each component is is neither relevant nor necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is simply incorrect. most hard drives can deal with component temps of less than 55c, and CPUs vary in their heat capacity between 70 and 100C. it is quite possible for these components to reach those temperatures and start to harm themselves, while the ambient box temp is 40C.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specs of your system/components. In general though, 40C (104F -- quite plausible for ambient "room temperature") should be safe for everything.

It is actually quite common for may computers to switch off their fans when not needed in an effort to conserve power (laptops) or reduce noise.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not recommend disabling other fans, especially based on estimates gathered when the machine is not under a signifigant load. Idle temp is not particularly useful for decision making.

Additionally the top fan should be exhaust, and it is recommended that you have a fan providing air input, as well as output. Third, if you are going to go with one case fan, use the rear fan behind the CPU. drawing CPU heat up can cause issues for the powersupply and it is usually mounted above the CPU.

Instead, since you have the ASUS tools, I'd recommend you create a cooling profile in Thermal Radar, that scales fans up or down based on sensor statuses. for instance, turning up the rear exhaust when CPU+VCore1+VCSA get high will help cool those components. turning up the assistant fan when the SATA controller, USB3 or PCI-E controllers heat up is another good recipie. This way your system is constantly adjusting itself to deal with whatever load you throw at it.

Comment: Anyway it couldn't be done in real life, when I leave 1 intake and 1 outtake fan the overall system get's hot quite fast. So I just tuned my Thermal Radar and all the fans are working on the lowest speed about 250-350 rpm and start to increase the speed after 35-39C. On this speed the airflow is low to moderate, but it's super quiet and when the temperature hits 65-70C everything will spin on max speed. The CPU is always at lower temperature than almost all other components.

Comment: sounds like you found a good profile for your purposes. personally i like things a bit cooler, so i'm always willing to sacrifice quiet for cool. for modern casesi generally recommend 4 fans, 2 in (front and side), and 2 out (Back and Top), but whatever fits your rig.